# how to expand a child div than a parent with dynamic width on 100% of body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to build a menu inside an element which can have different width and different positions of the page.

I would like to create an edit menu which appears when hover on element,but I need the menu is as wide as the entire page

I need to use **position:absolute** as not to "disturb" the page layout

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bkoqv52e/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-6 left">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 right">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content-right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container {
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    padding:30px;
}
nav {
    height:30px;
    background:#999;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;
    left:0;
}
.left {
    background:#ddd;
    height:300px;
}
.right {
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
.col-md-6:hover > nav {
    display:block;
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated! thanks

Comment: I will put my answer here is not much of a solution http://jsfiddle.net/bkoqv52e/1/.  the problem is bootstrap put a position in your col.  so the nav can't break it.  but if you remove the position it will work.

Comment: @Pik_at Great solution,  I have never use `static` before,  so I updated mine http://jsfiddle.net/bkoqv52e/2/

Comment: Thanks! I was lostto top position that busts all, without this work finally! I was silly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without js, you can define .left and .right to position static in order to refer nav to container on position relative like:

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    padding:30px;
  position: relative;
}
nav {
    height:30px;
    background:#999;
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
.left {
    background:#ddd;
    height:300px;
    position: static;
}
.right {
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:100px;
    position: static;
}
.col-md-6:hover > nav {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-md-6 left">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 right">
        <nav>nav</nav>
        <div class="content">content-right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```